# Android AVD throws errors, such as "Failed to sync vcpu reg"

Tags: android-emulator, avd-manager, intel-haxm

[How do I fix “Failed to sync vcpu reg” error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024538/how-do-i-fix-failed-to-sync-vcpu-reg-error) does not help. I tried all the solutions I could for Mac on the post but none worked.

I started a new project and tried to run the emulator, but I get these errors:

```
HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
emulator: Failed to sync vcpu reg
emulator: Failed to sync HAX vcpu context
```

It used to work yesterday. I didn't change/download anything.

Why did it stop working? I also made sure there are no other processes of the emulator running.

I'm running Android Studio in OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Are you using any VM's running in your Mac? Please stop and check if any running. Also look into [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29270617/1793718). It says you can restart the computer and start the emulator first before running any other programs. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that you're not running any other virtual machines, then try again.

I was running a guest Windows 8 VirtualBox on El Capitan and I got the same error when I tried to run a virtual Android device in Android Studio. I shutdown the guest OS and VirtualBox then my AVD booted up.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it's the docker program conflict with AVD, quit docker then restart the AVD is ok.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google Issue Tracker #37076131 - [Emulator] HAXM ioctl failed on Mac when trying to restore vcpu state](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37076131#comment85),

> Considering the bug fixed: HAXM 6.1.1 (available as a part of Android Studio or on Intel website at https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager76 ) is designed to coexist with Docker/VirtualBox/HVF hypervisors on Mac OS

Install latest version https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager and it works